# What are the parts that a good C++ project should contain? (Docs, Makefile, Tests etc...)

Tags: c++, project-management

i am writing my bachelor thesis and there is some C++ code attached to it.
I want to have a nice clean Project.

So what should be in it ?

I think :

- Documentation in html ( generated with Doxygen)
- README File
- Makefile ( which make ? CMake ? )
- Unit-Tests ( which unit test framework? )
- Copyright Text ?
- ...

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Mention dependencies if any in your readme as well

Comment: also make sure that the delivery is standalone as much as possible, nothing is so annoying as having to install 38 products to get your project compiled and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the list:

- Documentation in a place and form that can easily be found and read, including

  - instructions on how to build it;
  - instructions on how to use it.
- Some sort of confidence testing ("I compiled it, but does it *work*?").

Whether the docs are HTML, plain text or in-source comments; whether there's a Makefile or a batch script or a copy & paste one-liner in the README.txt; whether you've got a full-blown unit testsuite or a "golden file" test:

It doesn't matter really.

The important thing is that you can *build* it, *test* it, and *use* it as easily as possible.

---

Adding personal opinion:

KISS. (Keep it short and simple.)

Go with simple source comments for small projects, and only start the Doxygen stuff when you grow beyond a certain point. Make sure your documentation framework doesn't make it *harder* to find things via full-text search, because in my experience, that's what people end up doing unless you wrote your docs *really* well.

Go with a simple Makefile and use more sophisticated stuff (like CMake, automake etc.) only when it becomes necessary. For small projects, the amount of "metadata" in comparison to "real" source files can become ridiculous.

You can sink quite some time and energy in this "supporting cast", which - in the beginning of a project - should be put into the project itself. Build system, documentation etc. can grow as necessary, but the project architecture itself is a bitch to refactor once it's been released. That's where your primary focus should be.